# AngularJS and Symfony2 Forms or how to remove form's "action" attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, forms, symfony

I have Symfony form (FormType) and want to use AngularJS and `ng-submit` on client-side, but Symfony adds an `action` attribute to the form and ng-submit doesn't prevent form submission and page reload.

2 possible solutions:

1. How I can remove `action` attribute in Symfony form?
2. How I can call `preventDefault()` (or something similar) inside my Angular controller?

Comment: How about you render the form template manually?

Comment: @ferdynator I'm using {{ form(myFormVar) }} to render form, but if I set "action" attribute in Twig or PHP to NULL, FALSE, TRUE, "" and other gives zero results -- Symfony will render form with empty action attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. I just extend the `form_start` block in my base form theme:

```
{%- block form_start -%}
    {% set method = method|upper %}
    {%- if method in ["GET", "POST"] -%}
    {% set form_method = method %}
{%- else -%}
    {% set form_method = "POST" %}
{%- endif -%}
    <form name="{{ name }}" method="{{ form_method|lower }}" {% if action|length %}action="{{ action }}"{% endif %}{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
    {%- if form_method != method -%}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="{{ method }}" />
{%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_start -%}
```

What's new is the added `if`:

```
{% if action|length %}action="{{ action }}"{% endif %}
```

Comment: I doubt it is the only solution. I'm searching right now and post the answer later